# How to add cssClass on a grid cell in syncfusion

Tags: css, grid, cell, syncfusion

How can i set style property on a specific cell using syncfusion grid grouping control. I tried by below code but it's not working in webform.

```
tdescriptor.Columns[0].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.CssClass = "hideColumn";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this below code you can apply the cssClass for specific column. For getting the column we have to use TableDescriptor.Try with this below code

```
this.GridGroupingControl1.TableDescriptor.Columns[2].Appearance.AnyRecordFieldCell.CssClass = "MyClass";
```

For applying css for specific cell you can try this below code

```
if (((Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.GridCell)(e.Row.Cells[i])).ColumnDescriptor.Name == "ShipCity")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "MyClass";
                }
```